# I would like to parent and child SAMURAI SWORD to a samurai

Tags: animation, rigging, parent

How to parent and child SAMURAI SWORD as a decoration to a samurai using an automatic rigging add-on called Auto Rig Pro?

A samurai consists of a separate object for each part.

I added SAMURAI SWORD to the body, but it didn't come with the animation.

So I tried to select various things in Object properties> Relations> Parent, but there was no option that came with the animation.

It's just a decorative item, so it always sticks to your waist.[image]

Comment: if you want one hand to control the sword you can use the method explained by Lowlande, if you want both hands to hang the sword you can give a Child Of constraint to the hand bones with the sword as target, and the sword will be the controller

Comment: Sorry for late reply... I didn't know Child of constraint so Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the sword, in `Object Properties` tab set the parent to the Armature/Rig, change type to `Bone` and select the bone you want to use. You can reposition the sword and it will stay "fixed" relative to the bone you picked.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for so late reply.. I spend so many times this problem so you save me ; ; It works! Thank you so much!!